# How to set the end time of a scheduled task in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I know I can schedule a starting time for a task using `C-c C-s`, but is there a way to set a scheduled end time for a task? So that I can see my scheduled range in the agenda view, as follows.

```
Week-agenda (W16):
Monday     13 April 2020 W16
Tuesday    14 April 2020
Wednesday  15 April 2020
Thursday   16 April 2020
Friday     17 April 2020
Saturday   18 April 2020
               8:00...... ----------------
              10:00...... ----------------
              12:00...... ----------------
              14:00...... ----------------
  TODO:       14:30 ~ 16:00...... Scheduled:  TODO Start development
              16:00...... ----------------
              18:00...... ----------------
              19:50...... now - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
              20:00...... ----------------
Sunday     19 April 2020
  TODO:       10:30 ~ 11:00...... Scheduled:  TODO Start making videos
```

Notice that this is my estimated end time, not the actual one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, it's simple, just add the end time when scheduling, as follows:

```
* TODO Start development
  SCHEDULED: <2020-04-18 Sat 14:30-15:30>
```

This is the result.

```
Saturday   18 April 2020
               8:00...... ----------------
              10:00...... ----------------
              12:00...... ----------------
              14:00...... ----------------
  test:       14:30-15:30 TODO Start development
              16:00...... ----------------
              18:00...... ----------------
              20:00...... ----------------
              23:56...... now - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```